# Send thymeleaf table value to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to send my thymeleaf table row to controller using ajax according to button click. Below how I try so far

```
<button id="sisi" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" th:text="#{aji}">

<tr id="rikaList" th:each="rika:${allRikas}">
     <td th:text="${rika.customer.customerNumber}"></td>
     <td th:text="${rika.customer.customerName}"></td>
     <td th:text="${rika.customer.nicNo}"></td>
</tr> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#sisi").on('click', function () { 
        var contents = $("#rikaList").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/bow/generateReport/" + contents,
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Below you can see my controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/bow/generateReport/{rikaList}")
public void getCustomerByBranch(@PathVariable List<Rika> rikaList) {

}
```

Comment: None of your ids are matching.  Where is the id `#sisi` or the id `#rikaList`? They are both specified in your JavaScript, but not the html.

Comment: @Metroids edit with correct id

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've understand what you want to do but I think you should use POST and send the list inside the body.

Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/bow/generateReport")
public void getCustomerByBranch(@RequestBody List<Rika> rikaList) {

}
```

JS:

```
var rikaList = [] //create the list with values you need
var request = $.ajax({
    url : '/bow/generateReport',
    type : 'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify(rikaList),

    ...
});
```

How to create the list:

You have defined tr with id, maybe you want to put the id into parent, because the th:each will repeat the tr with the id I think.
So, with id into  tag instead :

```
var rikaList = []
    $('#rikaList > tbody > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
        var rika = {
            customerNumber: tr.cells[0].innerText, 
            customerName:tr.cells[1].innerText, 
            nicNo:tr.cells[2].innerText}
        rikaList.push(rika)
    });
```

There will be better ways to iterate through the table but if the structure is always the same yo can create the object list.

Comment: I want to send rikaList values. not created list

Comment: So your problem is how to create a list with the values that exists in the table? You can iterate, create the object and push into a list.

Comment: I don't need convert one by one, I need convert arraylist to json object at one time.